# How to find the name of the account under which Hadoop will execute jobs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, hadoop

I am trying to connect to my azure cluster and use hadoop from Visual Studio 2010.
I following these instruction:

```
https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20jobs%20on%20Azure%20HDInsight%20service
```

Looks like I have all information keyin right, except one field I am not very sure:

```
string hadoopUserName = "{HadoopAccount}";
```

I tried both: `Hadoop` and `hdp` but noon of this work. It returns this error:

```
 ..at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.HadoopImplementations.HadoopOnAzure.Create(Uri clusterName, String userName, String hadoopUserName, String password, String storageAccount, String storageKey, String container, Boolean createContainerIfMissing)
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Hadoop.<.cctor>b__2(Uri cluster, String user, String hadoopUser, String password, String account, String key, String container, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Hadoop.Connect(Uri clusterName, String userName, String hadoopUser, String password, String storageAccount, String storageKey, String container, Boolean createContainerIfMissing)
   at HadoopTestApp.Program.azureConnect() in C:\Users\sandeep.dixit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HadoopTestApp\HadoopTestApp\Program.cs:line 84
```

So I really have no clue what is wrong here and is there anyway I can test and find out which field is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft's [Provision Hadoop clusters in HDInsight by using custom options](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-provision-clusters/):

> The $hadoopUserName and $hadoopUserPassword commands are used to
>   create the Hadoop user account for the cluster. You will use this
>   account to connect to the cluster and run jobs. If you use the Quick
>   Create option from the Azure portal to provision a cluster, the
>   default Hadoop user name is "admin".

Comment: I think what you are mentioning is Cluster username. Yes, I use quick create option and I do notice that the Cluster username is "admin" by default. However, the Hadoop username here, I often see user use "hadoop" or "hdp" in their code (please refer to link on my post). I think this hadoop username may be created in local machine, not Azure (?).